# Transferring of .csv file from a location in my PC to Unix environment

Tags: shell

please explain the below shell scripting for me because it is not working.

```
sed "s/,/|/g" $csvFile |awk -F "|" '{ print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5"|"}' > dataFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, a CSV file is a CSV file no matter the environment. CSV just stands for 'comma separated values'.

Regarding your command, the first part

```
sed "s/,/|/g" $csvFile
```

takes the file name from the variable csvFile and replaces the commas with pipes (|).

The second part,

```
awk -F "|" '{ print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5"|"}'
```

takes the output from the 'sed' command in columns and prints them with pipes in between.

The third part

```
> dataFile.txt
```

puts the output of the commands into a text file called dataFile.txt.

To debug the command, we'll need to see your input file data and also what you are trying to write. The command as-is is redundant, but without seeing your input we don't know how to get it working (and improved).

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `sed` hhere. You can directly use awk with different field separator:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 OFS}' OFS='|' "$csvFile" > dataFile.txt
```